# let* equivalent for interactive

Tags: interactive, let-binding

I'd like to call a series of `completing-read` prompts via `interactive`, where every prompt after the first takes the previous result as its only argument.

```
(defun make-prompt ()
  (completing-read "Make: " '("Mazda" "Honda")))

(defun model-prompt (make)
  (completing-read "Model: "
                   (pcase make
                     ("Mazda" '("3" "Miata"))
                     ("Honda" '("Fit" "Accord")))))

(defun build-car (make model)
  (interactive (list (make-prompt) (model-prompt make)))
  (message "%s %s" make model))
```

In this example, `(model-prompt make)` is problematic because `make` is not defined by the time `model-prompt` is called. My presumption is that `make` isn't bound until the call to `interactive` finishes.

Is there an equivalent to `let*` for interactive forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a `let*` in the interactive form just use it:

```el
(defun build-car (make model owner)
  (interactive (let* ((make (make-prompt))
                      (model (model-prompt make)))
                  (list make model (owner-prompt make model))))
  (message "%s %s %s" make model owner))
```

Note, I added a fictive `owner` argument because without it even an
`(interactive (let ((make (make-prompt))) (list make (model-prompt make))))`
would be sufficent.

---

If you have a function `build-car` that is for interactive use only you can also use `cl-defun`:

```el
(defun make-prompt ()
  (interactive)
  (read-string "make-prompt: "))
(defun model-prompt (make)
  (read-string (format "model-prompt (%s): " make)))
(defun owner-prompt (make model)
  (read-string (format "owner-prompt (%s %s): " make model)))
(cl-defun build-car (&key
             (make (make-prompt))
             (model (model-prompt make))
             (owner (owner-prompt make model)))
  (interactive)
  (message "%s %s %s" make model owner))
```

If you want to use this version for functions that can also be called non-interactively, the alternative version becomes a bit dirtier:

```el
(cl-defun build-car (&key
              gui
              (make (or (and gui (make-prompt))
                 "default make"))
              (model (or (and gui (model-prompt make))
                 "default model"))
              (owner (or (and gui (owner-prompt make model))
                 "default owner")))
  (interactive '(:gui t))
  (message "%s %s %s" make model owner))
```

Comment: Ah, good point. I was trying too hard to translate it into a list of prompts.